# Nullreference exception in Update.Setwrap after updating Mongo Driver

Tags: c#-4.0, mongodb

I am in Mongo-C# environment and we have been coding against Mongo for a while using Mongo 1.3.x DLL. Recently, I updated it to be 1.4.2 and everything else was fine until I faced a problem where I noticed that while previous version of Mongo DLL was treating

```
update.SetWrapped(property.Name, value);
```

all file when value was null but the recent version does not like it and it throws nullreference exception.

Problem here is that I would like it to be able to accept Null values. has anybody faced this problem before? If yes, how did you handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a breaking change when this was introduced.  You need to use BsonNull.Value for this.  So, your code would look like this:

```
update.SetWrapped(property.Name, BsonValue.Create(value) ?? BsonNull.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Craig... I saw it on the site.... I don't know what can be a possible reason for them to make it explicit? what does it earn?

Comment: Well, internally, .NET null is handled differently that BsonNull.Value.  They semantically mean different things and under certain circumstances, it can be ambiguous.  So, there are rules that will get clarified with the next release (1.5).  1) When working with BsonDocument (untyped documents), then null is illegal.   2) when working with Classes (typed documents), then null gets mapped to BsonNull.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have been able to pass C# null to Update.SetWrapped<T> because T is a POCO and not a BsonValue and the serializer for T would decide how to serialize C# null.

I've created a JIRA ticket for this:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-486

Note that while C# driver versions earlier than 1.4 did not throw a NullReferenceException, they also did not update the property to BSON null as you might have expected (passing C# null to SetWrapped turned the SetWrapped into a no-op in earlier versions).

The basic rules for C# null handling are clear:

1. C# null is not a valid BsonValue, use BsonNull.Value instead
2. C# null is valid for POCOs, and will probably be serialized as a BSON null (although technically a serializer for a POCO could choose a different representation)